# getSupportActionBar crashes my app

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to use actionbar in my application, however getSupportActionBar crashes my app.

This was working, but I don't know what I've done to make it crash (I've remove everything and tried again, it keeps crashing ).

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainMenu extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        v.setBackgroundColor(0xffECECEC);


    }

    /*
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu);
        return true;
    }
    */
    public void play(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, Levels.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

Comment: post the manifest file. and why this  `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` remove it

Comment: alos post the stacktrace since you mention crash

Comment: @Raghunandan this so it will be full screen

Comment: then there will be no actionbar and what is the use of this    `ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();` then?

Comment: @Raghunandan removed it and worked, but how can I make it fullscreen with actionbar?

Comment: @Raghunandan fixed it by adding "getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);" thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want actionbar then you can adjust your code like below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    v.setBackgroundColor(0xffECECEC);


}
```

We should not write the actionbar code before setContentView() method.

And if you want full screen then there is no use of actionBar in your activity.

Answer (score -1):

when i was directly using getSupportActionBar() method my app was crashed instead of that i am using
 ActionBar actionbar=getSupportActionBar();
then you can do and perform any operation on action bar like actionbar.show(),actionbar.hide() and other operations.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to add anything new to the already accepted one. Plus it is badly formatted and worded, so I'm actually not sure if you missed the topic or not. Please only write an answer to an old question if something changed (like a version update of something), so that the actual answer is not true anymore or you can provide an better/easier method to archive the same.